# Exception setting volume of audio

Tags: javascript, audio

Why does this give error of `Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1`?

```
$(".S").html('<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="R/sopen.mp3"type="audio/mp3" /></audio>');      
audio.play();
audio.volume=0;
audio.addEventListener('ended',function(){
   this.currentTime=0;
   this.play();
},false); 
vol = 0; 
var fadein=setInterval(function(){
    if(vol<1){
        vol=vol + 0.1;
        audio.volume = vol;
    }else{
        audio.removeEventListener('ended');
        clearInterval(fadein);
    }
},100);
```

I just can't seem to crack it, also what does this error mean?

It seems to be happening here: `audio.volume=vol;`

This is the most non explanatory error I've ever seen! Tried google over and over, no luck in there.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code where you initialize `audio`.

Comment: thats all the code there! what do you mean?

Comment: Your second line of code is `audio.play()`.  Where is `audio` initialized?